# Why does not this regex work in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

my query:

```
SELECT  *  FROM `tblforummessages`
WHERE `FMMessage` REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9 :,.!?éáőúöüóűíÉÁŐÚÖÜÓŰÍ()\t\n\r\-\"\„]{9,}$'
```

my text is:

> "Kedves Marietta! Szeretném tájékoztatni, hogy véradós jeggyel az
>   összes medencét (13 db), valamint az összes szaunát (4 db)
>   használhatja. Felhívnám a figyelmét, hogy a véradós jegyet vasárnap
>   kivételével bármelyik nap felhasználhatja 2009. december 23-ig."

online validators said this text pass for this expression, but in sql it dont work
i tried to use

```
CAST(`FMMessage` AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

but didnt help.

Comment: Your regex contains \", is your query being ran in a double quoted string? If so all that does is escape the double quote, and could screw up your regex

Comment: You have right, \" block my query, but i need to filter by both type (" and „) how can i do than that?

Comment: Not sure `„` is OK, but the `-` must be at the end of the bracket expression. And unescaped. Not sure about the whitespaces either. Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9 :,.!?éáőúöüóűíÉÁŐÚÖÜÓŰÍ()\t\n\r"„-]{9,}$`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support multi-byte characters in REGEXP.

To check that the entire `FMMessage` is at least 9 characters, use `CHAR_LENGTH(FMMessage) >= 9`.  It is unclear what the rest of the REGEXP is trying to do.  You seem to have all the possible characters in normal Hungarian text, but exclude some (not all) other European texts.  English is allowed, some German is not because of the double-s.

Assuming the encoding is utf8 (or utf8mb4), it would probably be possible to do

```
HEX(FMMessage) REGEXP '...'
```

where the regexp is a long string of 2- and 4-character hex pairs separated by `|`.  The entire regexp would be about 300 chars long.